# Checking if parent node has specific child

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I need to find the parents in an XML file which contain a specific tag, and then need to parse the strings from those parents and their children into a Java object, or array (could also use some advice on the best way to store the XML info as strings).

```
<task>
    <task id=483492>
    <project id=484383>
        <date>2003/23/03</date>
    <name> project name example </name>
</task>
<task>
    <task id=483492>
    <name> task name example </name>
</task>
<task>
    <task id=483492>
    <project id=484383>
        <date>2003/23/03</date>
    <name> project name example </name>
</task>
<task>
    <task id=483492>
    <project id=484383>
        <date>2003/23/03</date>
    <name> project name example </name>
</task>
<task>
    <task id=483492>
    <name> task name example </name>
</task>
```

So, if a `<task>` parent has a `<project>` child, I need to put the data from each `<task>`'s children into some kind of list/array/object.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: I can't give you sample code at this moment but use XPath for that. PS. Most SO users will think it's your homework by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, not homework though, I'm working on an Android app. I'd leave sample code but my attempts are just way too far off to be relevant. I'll try leaving some when I get a chance. I've already completed most of the parsing in DOM, would it make sense to mix XPath with it ?(the above is just a segment, actual XML file is much larger) Never used it before, so not sure.